# Ideas on how can i implement a decision criteria matrix in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, criteria, decision-tree

like the title said, i need to implement a decision matrix, one like the image below but with n amount of criteria and n amount of decision
[image]

I've thought on using a Dictionary where i can store the Criteria and Decision and the value, like `Dictionary<DecisionCriteria, int>` and class DecisionCriteria would be:
`class DecisionCriteria { string Criteria; string Decision; }`
but i don't know if thats is a good idea.

Another possible solution would imply something like a string array for each row
`string[] row = {"U Delaware" , "12", "57", "16".....}`, but i also don't think this would be very efficient.

I appreciate your ideas. Thanks

I have not started coding yet, i need to have an idea first

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible example of creating a `DecisionCriteria` class, populating a list of `DecisionCriteria`s, sorting the list and getting the top choice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        //Create a list of DecisionCriteria obejects.
        List<DecisionCriteria> dcList = new List<DecisionCriteria>();
        
        //Create a new DecisionCriteria and add to the list.
        DecisionCriteria dc = new DecisionCriteria("U Delaware");
        dc.AddCriteria("Distance", 12);
        dc.AddCriteria("Social Life", 57);
        //Add more criteria if needed;
        dcList.Add(dc);
        
        //Create a new DecisionCriteria and add to the list.
        dc = new DecisionCriteria("Syracuse");
        dc.AddCriteria("Distance", 36);
        dc.AddCriteria("Social Life", 38);
        //Add more criteria if needed;
        dcList.Add(dc);
        
        //Add more DecisionCriteria objects to the list if needed.
        
        //Sort the list;
        dcList.Sort((a,b) => b.TotalBenefit.CompareTo(a.TotalBenefit));     //Sort Descending
        //dcList.Sort((a,b) => a.TotalBenefit.CompareTo(b.TotalBenefit));   //Sort Ascending.
        
        //Get best choice
        DecisionCriteria bestChoice = dcList[0];
        
        Console.WriteLine("Best Choice is: " + bestChoice.EntityName + " with value: " + bestChoice.TotalBenefit.ToString() );
    }
    
    //Create a class to hold the criteria for each entity.
    public class DecisionCriteria
    {
        //Properties to hold the name and criteria data.
        public string EntityName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,int> Criteria { get; set; }    
        
        //Constructor takes a name (i.e. "U of Delaware")
        public DecisionCriteria(string EntityName) {
            this.EntityName = EntityName;
            Criteria = new Dictionary<string,int>();  //Make sure Criteria property is initialized with an empty dictionary.
        }
        
        //Add up all the criteria to get a total.
        public int TotalBenefit {
            get 
            {
                //You can modify this to calculate the total benefit. You might have some criteria that decrement the total value instead of incrementing it (detractors vs benefits). Or apply weighting to some criteria.
                int sum = 0;
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Criteria) {
                    sum += kvp.Value;
                }
                return sum;
            }
        }
        
        //Use to add criteria to the entity/this object
        public void AddCriteria(string Name, int Value) {
            Criteria.Add(Name, Value);
        }
    }
}
```